# how to reference where the length between two occurrences is similar in the past to how it is now

Tags: for-loop, statistics, pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
var crossover_count = 0
var crossunder_count = 0

buy_cross(src, line) =>
    ta.crossover(src, line)
sell_cross(src, line) =>
    ta.crossunder(src, line)

add_crossover_count = if buy_cross(line_choice, smooth_line)
    crossover_count += 1 
add_crossunder_count = if sell_cross(line_choice, smooth_line) 
    crossunder_count += 1 

var get_curr_barval_long = 0
var get_curr_barval_short = 0
bar_val_long = if add_crossover_count
    get_curr_barval_long := ta.barssince(add_crossunder_count)
bar_val_short = if add_crossunder_count 
    get_curr_barval_short := ta.barssince(add_crossover_count)

long_forward = get_curr_barval_long + 5 
long_backward = get_curr_barval_long - 5 
short_forward = get_curr_barval_short + 5 
short_backward = get_curr_barval_short - 5 

var sim_found = false
prev_bar_val_long = for i = get_curr_barval_long to 2500
    if get_curr_barval_long[i] >= long_backward and get_curr_barval_long[i] <= long_forward
        sim_found := true 
    else if get_curr_barval_long[i] <= long_backward or get_curr_barval_long[i] >= long_forward
        sim_found := false
```

Im using a regression line (line_choice) and its average (smooth_line) and getting the amount of bars in between crossovers and crossunders. What im trying to do is then test in historical bars where the length in between is similar (within +- 5 bars) and be able to reference the times there was similarity found (sim_found).